# How to insert a new column to a row using CQL

Tags: cassandra, fluentcassandra

i would like to know how to use CQL to insert a new column to a row...

Is it possible?
If not, how can i do that easily by using Fluent Cassandra?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

CQL expects you to define your schema up front.  If you want dynamic schema, you must use one of the Thrift-based clients.  Fluent Cassandra supports this; [check here](http://coderjournal.com/2010/06/your-first-fluent-cassandra-application/).

Comment: when you say schema up front do you say that before i do a insert that have a new column i have to execute a CQL like: ALTER TABLE messages ADD ColunaTeste varchar; ? Is that correct? Well, i did it here and worked, is here some problem in do this? Thanks!

Comment: Yes you have do the alter prior to the insert.  CQL requires the schema, as it's a facade on top of the underlying storage rows.  Cassandra itself doesn't care, but the CQL engine does.

Answer (score 0):

Using FluentCassandra, you can add a new column to an existing row quite easily:

```
var cFamily = db.GetColumnFamily("TestCF");
cFamily.InsertColumn(rowKey, columnName, columnValue);
```

Alternatively, you can do it like this:

```
var cFamily = db.GetColumnFamily("TestCF");
var record = cFamily.CreateRecord(existingRowKey) //record already exists
record[newColumnName] = newColumnValue;
```

Comment: Its worth noting that, after taking some rudimentary timings, it appears that the latter solution (CreateRecord) is around 3 times faster than using InsertColumn.

Answer (score 0):

Using FluentCassandra:

```
dbcontext.ExecuteNonQuery("update TargetColumnFamily set 'ColumnName'='ColumnValue' 
   where keyname='RowKeyValue'")
```

In my testing, I've found this will create the row if it doesn't exist.  Not sure how to tweak this for non-text.